# Error message on creating keystore using Android Magazine App Maker

Tags: android

I want to make android book using Android Magazine App Maker, but I got stuck when creating keystore. It always shows error message. I need help.

This is screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is some info [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.noclassdeffounderror%20sun.security.x509.certandkeygen).

Answer (score 1):

Here solution,

1. Download and Setup "java jdk" [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
2. you just right click on "my computer icon on desktop.

   - Go to "properties".
   - Then Go to "Advanced".
   - Then go to "environment variables"
     where the java path is set in path or may be classpath or JAVA_HOME ..
   - Delete all java path..
   - Now again take a new path variable and set java path in it which is mostly C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin
      then save it. . . . . . . .

Please note:

1) if you do not have " java jdk " then download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

2) Set jdk path according to your version, like, in my computer, version is 1.8.0_45.

Comment: Please do not unnecessarily use URL shortening services, they hide information about where the link leads to. If you *do* use a shortening service, please use one that does not require the user to pass through an ad first. You have done this in a number of your answers.